# How to access the resource files that are kept under resources folder

Tags: java, unit-testing, testing, testng

How to get the absolute path of the files(cacerts.pem,client.pem,client-key.pem) that are kept under the folders as below in the image

This is in the eclipse and gradle environment[image]

Comment: Where is the image?

Comment: In general, you don't get the absolute path. When you deploy that project, these resources will not be files. They will be objects inside your jar. Resources like that should only be accessed through the class loader.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I usually use a cheat to get there!

```
Paths.get(SomeClass.class.getClassLoader().getResource("").toURI());
```

When the java code is built all resources go to their target output, for example you would have something like target/io/geocloud/management/client/* .

For you specific problem i would change a bit the code and do something like

```
Paths.get(SomeClass.class.getClassLoader().getResource("io/geocloud/management/client/ca/cacerts.pem").toURI()).toAbsolutePath().toString();
```

Answer (score 0):

Using Spring:

```
Resource resource = new ClassPathResource("file/location/cert.pem");
File file = resource.getFile();
```